# "are specified" or "have been specified" would be grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Which one is correct?

> The conditions of deformation and calculation of the soil – pipeline system are specified?

Or:

> The conditions of deformation and calculation of the soil – pipeline system have been specified?

Comment: They are both *grammatically* correct but they are used in different contexts. You need to tell us *where* they are specified and *when* they were specified.

Comment: They were specified as a result of the scientific research. I'll give a whole abstract with some corrections:  "There have been specified the conditions of deformation and calculation of the soil – pipeline system. Analytical dependences have been obtained for describing the processes occurring in the system under consideration. An illustrative visualization of the stress-strain state in the soil thickness is presented."

Answer (score 0):

*Are* is in the present tense, whereas *have been* is in the past tense.

Therefore, if hey have just been specified use:

> The conditions of deformation and calculation of the soil – pipeline system are specified?

If they have been specified for a while, use:

> The conditions of deformation and calculation of the soil – pipeline system have been specified?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with D Manokhin and I'll add another point of view.

(1) In other papers on the subject, the conditions have been specified. Our research is based on those prior conditions.

(2) In this paper, the conditions (on which we base our conclusions) are specified.